# Google spreadsheet to custom XML

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I am trying to export a Google spreadsheet to XML. I ve searched for function ContentService.MimeType.XML but dont understand how to can set the parameters. DO you happen to have a simple example showing how you load and display the XML content?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a couple of ways to do this. One way is to use the Spreadsheet API. Google is now on version 3.0 of the API so any v1 or v2 code no longer works.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

The other thing you can do is publish the the spreadsheet to an ATOM or RSS feed. If you go to File -> "Publish to the Web", Under the "Get a link to the published data" from the drop down you can select, ATOM or RSS and grab the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have also search for various options as my work depend on it. I googling a vast but not find any solution and solution in the forms such a content service doesn't work for me.  But this work for me may be for you too.

download the google spreadsheet as csv file and open it in excel and there select all (clt+A) and copy and paste in the link http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-xml.htm hope you get your required xml.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the post-mortem.

Try the *Templated Export for Spreadsheets* thingy explained [here](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2012/08/templated-export-for-google-spreadsheets/).

The trick consists of a script that can be imported to a spreadsheet to add exporting capabilities in a variety of formats. There's even a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CAHXLaCatA) explaining how to export a fragment of a sheet to JSON.